# Python Socket Receiver

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.x, socket, tcp

I put this together and am having some doubts to the number of connections I can make. I also doubt if I can brute force the server to serve up connections and then hang.

Please take a look and tell me what I can do better.

```
'''
    Simple socket server using threads
'''

import socket
import sys
from thread import *


HOST = '192.168.0.102'   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8887 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)

print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):


    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True: 


        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print data

        reply = 'OK...' + data + str(addr)
        if not data:
            break

        conn.sendall(reply)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Comment: - Use python-logging module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instead of print. It will be really useful for debugging once your system is live.

Answer (score 4):

This code is very nice and easy to follow along with.

---

You should check the return value of `socket.socket` to make sure that the socket was created successfully

---

Usually, the name given to an error in a `try`/`catch`(or `except`) statement is something along the lines of "err", not "msg".

---

You should pass an error code to `sys.exit` so that external programs will know if there were any errors during the execution of the program.

---

In the `while` loop of `clientthread`, you use `True` to specify an infinite loop.

However, in the `while` loop just below that function, you use `1`. You should stay consistent and use `True` for that one.

---

Instead of just printing the `data`, add a short message before it so the purpose of the number is more easily understood in output.

Example:

```
print 'Client data: ' + data
```

---

I don't believe that the `s.close` call at the end of your code will actually run.

This may not be necessary, as the socket may close automatically, but I would set up a signal handler to close the socket when someone tries to exit the program. You can use the `signal` library.

I came up with something like this:

```
def close_socket():
    s.close()
    sys.exit(0) # success
```

Then, right before your final `while` loop:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close_socket)
```